# WebGL doesn't work under Chrome in Windows 8 Developer Preview

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, webgl

Hi I was wondering if anyone else was having problems running WebGL in Windows 8 under Chrome.

I'm using Windows 8 Developer Preview x64 and Chrome 18.  My video card is a Nvidia 250 GTS.
If I try to run any WebGL page, running though javaScript or NativeClient both fail to load thinking my video card doesn't support it.

I have my own native OpenGL apps that use GL2 and GL3 API features... GL itself is not the issue, unless I don't understand how Chrome uses GLES2 features.
Are there any known bugs about this??  Can't find anything.

**EDIT:** I just installed 'Windows 8 **Consumer** Preview x64' and WebGL still does not work...  Is there a black list of OS's, kinda like some Intel video cards are black listed?? I have my system dual booted with Arch Linux and WebGL works fine on there?

Comment: First of all, the Developer Preview was a very early stage of Windows 8, now superseded by the Consumer Preview. You're running software on a very prerelease OS with likely unstable and prerelease drivers. Don't expect anything to work yet.

Comment: I had similar problem on Win8 CP and Radeon 5770, but recent update (week or so) fixed it. It seems they are working on these issues.

Comment: I had/have the same problem with Win8 CP. WebGL still doesn't work with Chrome for me but it works with Firefox.

Comment: pkr298: That sucks as I need WebGL to run under Chrome using native client, not javaScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround on windows 8 just add `--disable-gpu-sandbox` (I've checked it on 18 and 19 versions). To check open chrome://gpu/

For more information see [chromium issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112205)

Comment: Very nice... Worked for me tnx.  Will have to add that to my list of things to remember for Chrome.

Comment: Well now Chrome 19 came out... So this issue is gone for now.